# Go install not working with zsh

Tags: macos, unix, go, terminal, zsh

I feel like an idiot because I've installed this before on macOS and OSX but for some reason I can't see what I'm doing wrong. Please help!!! I've created a directory, `~/go`, which will be my workspace. When I run `go env` from my home directory I get `zsh: command not found: go` and I know it's because of the following files. What is wrong in my configuration?

**~/.bash_profile:**

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
```

**~/.zshrc:**

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
```

Comment: Have you sourced your `~/.zshrc` (or launched a new zsh instance) before running `go env`?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add that.

Comment: What happens if you run `/usr/local/go/bin/go env`?

Comment: When you run `echo $PATH`, does it actually contain `/usr/local/go/bin`?

Comment: is this question still unanswered/unresolved?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you installed on Mac OS not with home-brew but with the macOS package installer, your *GOBIN* be in [/usr/local/go](https://golang.org/doc/install) and *GOPATH* in [$HOME/go](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SettingGOPATH), finally in `~/.zshrc`:

```
  export GOPATH=$HOME/go
  export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
  export GOBIN=$GOPATH/bin
  export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH
  export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin
```

Comment: And do not use '~' to replace home path :(

Comment: I had to add `export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin` as well for zsh to pick up installed binaries

Answer (score 21):

Below config is working for me,

in `~/.zshrc`

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/golang
export GOROOT=/usr/local/opt/go/libexec
export GOBIN=$GOPATH/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin
```

You can see the configured details as below then

> `go env`

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN="/Users/my-name/golang/bin"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/my-name/golang"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/opt/go/libexec"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/opt/go/libexec/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="clang"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/6q/h6nchrdj49zgjfcp8wstj94r0000gn/T/go-build874871088=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
```

Comment: I wasn't able to execute binaries installed by Go. After adding $GOBIN as well to the path it worked.

Answer (score 9):

Installing `go` through brew didn't add the global `ENV` path in the shell profile. So, I had to manually add the following in the `~/.zshrc` file, and that was it!

```bash
export PATH="$PATH:$(go env GOPATH)/bin"
```

Note: If you are using `bash` or another shell, the name of the profile file will be different!

Comment: More clean and simple for someone who just want to run a go bin